# How do you update a component in React when new data arrives on a stream?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm using the [electron-boilerplate](https://github.com/szwacz/electron-boilerplate) and [Kurt Weiberth's tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQDnxXqV213JJFtDaG0aE9vqvp6Wm7nBg) to create my first node.js native app. I was able to create the app in the tutorial and now I want to add a component that gets updated when new tweets are streamed in given a query.

To do this, I created Tweet, TweetStream, and TweetFeed components, below. This kind of works, but I keep getting an error

> Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `###############`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.

There are no duplicates when I look at the state for tweets, so I'm not sure why React is encountering them. Have I put something in the wrong place? Putting the Twit stream in a Component doesn't feel right, but I'm not sure where else it could go. I'd like to be able to update the query at some point so it seems like it needs to respond to an event when the query is updated.

**Tweet**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Tweet extends Component {

  render() {
    return (<li>
      {this.props.tweet}
    </li>);
  }
}

export default Tweet;
```

**TweetStream**

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Tweet from './Tweet';

```
class TweetStream extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {
          this.props.tweets.map((tweet) => {
            return <Tweet key={tweet.id} tweet={tweet.text} />;
          })
        }
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default TweetStream;
```

**TweetFeed**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const express = require('express');
const Twit = require('twit');

const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

class TweetFeed extends Component {

  handleTweet(tweet) {

    this.state = {
      id: tweet.id,
      text: tweet.text
    };

    this.props.actions.addTweet(tweet);
  }

  render() {
    const ts = this;
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
      console.log('User connected. Socket id %s', socket.id);

      socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('User disconnected. %s. Socket id %s', socket.id);
      });
    });

    const T = new Twit({
      consumer_key: 'KEY',
      consumer_secret: 'SECRET',
      access_token: 'TOKEN',
      access_token_secret: 'TOKEN_SECRET',
      timeout_ms: 60 * 1000,  // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.
    });
    const stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: this.props.query });
    stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
      io.sockets.emit('tweet', tweet);
      ts.handleTweet(tweet);
    });

    return (<div />);
  }
}

export default TweetFeed;
```

**Tweets Reducer**

```
const initialTwitterState = [];

export default function reducer(state = initialTwitterState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TWEET':
      return [{id: action.text.id, text: action.text.text}, ...state];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

These are called from a Home component

```
// @flow
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styles from './Home.css';
import TodoInput from './TodoInput';
import TweetStream from './TweetStream'
import TweetFeed from './TweetFeed'
import * as TodoActions from '../actions/todo';
import * as TwitterActions from '../actions/twitter';


class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <div>
        <TweetStream tweets={this.props.tweets} actions={this.props.tweet_actions}/>
        <TweetFeed query={this.props.todos.query} tweets={this.props.tweets} todos={this.props.todos} actions={this.props.tweet_actions}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return state;
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(TodoActions, dispatch),
    tweet_actions: bindActionCreators(TwitterActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: `key={tweet.id}` this is the only place you're using a key, so you have tweets with the same ID. react will use the latest one and discard the older one, so you'd only see one in the DOM. check your data. If you need to display tweets with duplicate ids for some reason, use the index of the map

Comment: ugh... don't do data loading on the render method. Instead use the `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` methods for this.

Comment: Thanks Andy Ray. Simple enough and works.

Comment: Thanks Eldelshell. Like I said, loading in the render method didn't feel right. Loading on mounting makes sense.